# Compare two folders and copy the difference to a third folder

Tags: python, linux

[in this link you can see what I did](http://linuxfreelancer.com/how-do-you-compare-two-folders-and-copy-the-difference-to-a-third-folder)

I am beginner with python and I have to do the same for my work. (link included)
[filecmp- code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104185/how-do-you-compare-two-folders-and-copy-the-difference-to-a-third-folder/123874?noredirect=1#comment196758_123874) compare directories, take the different files. Everything okay with
`ls -1R /tmp/test/current/` & `ls -1R /tmp/test/old/`
 BUT for the third file and the most important does not give me any results.

```
ls -1R /users/diff/newdiff
```

I will appreciate your answer. What should I change to take results.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question `python` when you have linked a `python` solution in the other question? Also, if this *is* a `python` question, it is better placed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: An answer to _what_? What is it you're trying to do? What third file are you talking about? What do the `ls` commands have to do with anything? Why does it have to be done with python? Have you seen the answers on the question you linked to? Don't they work for you? Please [edit] your question and state precisely what you need to do and what you've tried. As it is, your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dircmp dir1 dir2
```

description is here: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udircmp.htm

works for Windows too. You may have to manipulate the output depending on what your needs are, but that should be fairly simple. I use it all the time.